# Transforming logarithmic expressions in a column from character to numeric class

Tags: r, excel

I've imported an excel file by using the XLConnect package:

```
 data <- loadWorkbook("C:/Users...")
 data <- readWorksheet(data, sheet = "Blad1")
```

The data consists of a mix of columns containing strings and numerics. Some columns contain exponential numbers in them such as : "8.55 × 10−23" (should be 10^-23). All those columns are imported as character vectors instead of numeric vectors, which I can understand. 
However I've tried some different ways to convert those columns to numeric vectors without succeeding:

1. Tried to (for column 9 in this case):

   ```
   data[, 9] <- gsub(" × 10", "*10^(", data[, 9])
   data[, 9] <- paste(data[, 9], ")", sep = "")
   ```

Which actually succeeds in making the exponential numbers look like: 8.94*10^(-11). And then I tried:

```
data[, 9] <- lapply(data[, 9], as.numeric)
print(data)
```

But I get NA's returned in that column.

I've also tried changing the numbers that turn out NA's into 8.94x10^(-11), 8.94*10^-11, 8.94*10E-11, 8.94*e(-11) (and other combinations), added / and // before the * and x and ^ (so as to read the signs as arithmetic operators and not characters), but it doesn't help. If I type in the expression 8.94*10^(-11) directly into the console it can evaluate it properly and becomes a numeric. I've also tried to make argument colTypes in readWorksheet but I haven't been able to get the grammatics correct (I think) and I haven't found examples on the internet that works (and I don't really understand the helpfiles for that argument).

It'd be really helpful if somebody has a solution as it feels like I'm really missing something apparent. I apologize beforehand for stupid question/bad explanation of the problem, I'm quite new to R... =)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Sincerely,

Sinael

EDIT:

My code, so far, looks something like this:

```
 GWAS_data <- function () {
    library(XLConnect)
    GWAS_data <- loadWorkbook("C:/Users...") #where the data is located on my computer

    GWAS_data2 <- readWorksheet(GWAS_data, sheet = "Blad1")

    GWAS_data2[, 9] <- gsub(" × 10", "\\*10\\^\\(", GWAS_data2[, 9])

 # Starting with just trying to transform column 9:

    GWAS_data2[, 9] <- paste(GWAS_data2[, 9], ")", sep = "")

    GWAS_data2[, 9] <- lapply(GWAS_data2[, 9], as.numeric)
            print(GWAS_data2)
            print(lapply(GWAS_data2, class))
```

And then I end up with column 9 being solely NA values... 
And the data is an .xls file with the first row of data looking like this, in a libre office document that I can't find out how to upload here =):

rs131 4 44870448    GNPDA2  T/C 0.44    0.067   0.007   8.94 × 10−11    4.29 × 10−18    1.58 × 10−23

Or if you prefer separated by commas:

rs131,  4, 44870448,    GNPDA2, T/C,    0.44,   0.067,  0.007,  8.94 × 10−11,   4.29 × 10−18,   1.58 × 10−23

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you get into this format with your conversion? 9.44e-10. This works when you convert to numeric from string.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply.

Succeeded in transforming the data to that format (i.e. 8.94e-11), but after using :

    data[, 9] <- lapply(data[, 9], as.numeric)

For that column I still get NA's returned... 

It makes that notation (9.44e-10) to numeric when I do it in the interface though...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try e format for scientific notation as follows:

```
s <- '8.94*10^(-11)'
s <- gsub("\\*10\\^", "e", s)
s <- gsub('\\(|\\)', '', s)
as.numeric(s)
[1] 8.94e-11
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!

It works fine to gsub the numbers into the scientific notation format (i.e. 8.94e-11), but then when I try to use as.numeric for the column I get NA values returned. For example I tried:

     data[1, 9] <- as.numeric(data[1, 9]) for 8.94e-11 

(first row, 9th column number) and then print the data, and that value gets returned as NA while all the rest in that column remains readable (but of course remains as characters and not numeric)....

Comment: There must be some other special characters? It is hard to address the issue without the data that is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay, been on vacation.

I've included the code in the question now, couldn't find a way to upload the data though but copied in the first row of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I solved it. First I changed the first part of the function, I used read.csv instead of using the XLConnect package. read.csv automatically transformed all "^" to "?", but I used gsub to change those into standard format, ie "8.94e-11".

However, I think the major problem was in the second part of the function:

```
  GWAS_data2[, 9] <- lapply(GWAS_data2[, 9], as.numeric)
```

I read somewhere that if its a single column the function regards it as a vector, and somehow the problem was solved when I wrote like this instead, and transformed column 9 through 11 instead of just column 9:

```
 GWAS_data2[, 9:11] <- lapply(GWAS_data2[, 9:11], as.numeric)
```

Don't quite understand why it worked yet, but I'm getting there. Thanks for the help!